# is there a way that i can tell if firefox is prefetching?

Tags: firefox, prefetch

I turned off prefetching and just want to confirm that firefox has stopped prefetching.  is there a way that i can check?  i tried looking at the cookies and network activity, but still couldn't tell.  thanks!

Comment: thanks for your answer!  is there a way to tell if google is prefetching the top result in my search?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've disabled `network.prefetch-next` in `about:config`, [Firefox should stop prefetching links](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-automatically-making-connections#w_link-prefetching).

You can check this by [observing the request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ#As_a_server_admin.2C_can_I_distinguish_prefetch_requests_from_normal_requests.3F) you're sending to potentially prefetched links by checking the [Network tab in your Firefox Dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Headers) or a Packet Analyzing software like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).